# Data annotations: DisplayName - How to show no display name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Maybe quite simple, but I have a property on my model for which I do not want to show a display name.

My guesses would be:

```
[Display()]
[Display(Name = "")]
```

Or maybe there's a better, yet unknown to me way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want a blank name?

Comment: @photo_tom is right. If you don't want to display name then just ignore it in a view

Comment: I have an Image property on my model. On the webpage, I just want the picture, no "Image" above it or anything. Ignoring it in the view is a good one.

Comment: Can you please supply your razor code showing how you wish to use this property?   In my MVC code, this wouldn't be an issue.